# Bing Maps in ASP.NET MVC web app doesn't show correctly in mobile view

Tags: ios, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bing-maps

I'm making an Web-App in ASP.NET MVC 5. It has to have a Bing Maps map and pushpins to show locations of some entities I retrieve the location of from a server. Everything works perfectly in a desktop browser, but when I switch over to mobile (iPhone etc.) the view is completely disorted as you can see in the image below:

[image: This is what the map shows...]

How is this possible? The view is totally incorrect, as for the zoom and center of the camera. Besides that it looks like the left half of the map is just zoomed in.

Comment: Note to others, the issue here is that an older version of Bing Maps which has limited support for mobile was being used. Migrating to the Bing Maps V8 web control is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added a viewport metatag to your application to prevent the page from scaling? Take a look at these best practices for cross platform apps with Bing Maps V8: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt793328.aspx

Comment: I did this indeed, but the page itself is good, its only the map itself that is glitched inside of the <div> where the map element is... The textures are all over the place.

Comment: Can you try loading in the Bing Maps interactive SDK to see if it does the same thing on your device: http://aka.ms/bmisdk We test the API on mobile devices with each release, so there isn't any reason why it shouldn't be loading correctly, unless something on your page is interfering with the map.

Comment: Do you want me to make the link available to you in private chat?

Comment: Sure, email me at richbrun at microsoft.com if you like.